# Export stl without applying boolean operation

Tags: modifiers

I am using Blender to make models for 3D printing.  I always export my .blend files to .stl files and import into MakerBot.

Lets say I'm making a model with two cubes that I want to glue together with a boolean "union" operation.  A very common pattern I've found is that I want to save my blender file with the two cubes separate, but every time I want to make an .stl file, I need to first apply the boolean operation, export as .stl, then close blender without saving.

Is there a way for me to export the .stl file as if I've applied the boolean operation, but keep the .blend file with the operation undone?  thanks.

Comment: you don't need to really apply the modifier, just check the option `apply modifiers ` in the export window

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Keep the modifiers in the file without applying and choose Apply modifiers in the exporter options , this way the exported objects will have the modifier applied but the original will not.

[image]